# Reading a js file in NodeJS and loading it on the client side

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am very new to node js. I want to upload a file to my local directory and read the file using node js. I then want to print the content of the js file into `<script> </script>` element in my index.html file on the client side.

I have following indext.html file

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div>
     <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/">
          <input type="file" name="filename">
          <input type="submit" value="upload">
     </form>
 </div>

 <div class="vis">  </div>
 </body>
 <script> </script>
</html>
```

I also have the following node js code:

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express(),
http = require("http").Server(app).listen(8000),
upload = require("express-fileupload")

var fs = require('fs');

app.use(upload())


console.log("Listening to port 8000");
app.get("/",function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname+"/index.html");
})

app.post("/", function(req,res){
   if(req.files){
      var file = req.files.filename,
        filename = file.name;
    file.mv("./uploads/"+filename,function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            res.send("err occurd");
        }
        else
        {   
            //content of the file
            var fileData= fs.readFileSync('./uploads/vis.js','utf8');
            // res.send(fileData)
        }
    })
  }
})
```

I can easily upload the file and read the conent of the file. What I want to do now is to copy the content of the file (in this case fileData) into the `<script>` on my front end. I am not sure how is that possible here. Any suggestion?

Comment: Why not have a reference in your script tags to the location of the vis.js file? Like <script src="vis.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Start by making another route which sends back the fileData.

```
app.get("/data", () => { 
   var fileData= fs.readFileSync('./uploads/vis.js','utf8');
   res.send(fileData)
})
```

Then on the frontend make a request to your new route and use a templating language like Nunjucks to dynamically fill in your HTML. If you use Nunjucks your route may end up looking like this:

```
app.get("/data", () => { 
   var fileData= fs.readFileSync('./uploads/vis.js','utf8');
   res.render('index', {fileData: fileData})
})
```

Lets continue with the nunjucks example and look at configuration. In your app.js configure nunjucks to look into your views folder. This configuration makes res.render work in the above route:

```
var nunjucks = require('nunjucks');
var env = nunjucks.configure('views', { noCache: true });
app.engine('html', nunjucks.render);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
```

Then in your index.html use nunjucks string interpolation. res.render will pass in the fileData variable:

```
{% block content %}
    <div>{{fileData}}</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you elaborate your answer a little bit more? using app.get on the front end? Does this work?

Comment: Thanks. It does not work for me. did you test this? I get this error when I am  running the server  Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "/Users/Boby/Desktop/VisML/NewVersion/views

Comment: @BahadorSaket What does your file structure look like? Do you have a views directory with an index.html file?

Comment: Project folder -> uploads folder,  app.js, index.html . Inside the uploads folder is vis.js

Comment: @BahadorSaket change your file structure or change the path that you pass to nunjucks.configure([path], [opts]); Also make sure you are serving up the index.html with express.static.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a form submit for upload, you can use Ajax for the upload and receive the uploaded file content.

Replace the `<form/>` with just a

```
 <input type='file' id='upload-input' name='file'>
```

and then have the following to handle upload

```
var uploadInput = document.getElementById('upload-input');

  uploadInput.addEventListener("change", function (evt) {
    if (evt.target.files.length === 0) {
      return;
    }

    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.addEventListener("load", function reqListener() {
      if (req.readyState === req.DONE) {
        if (req.status === 200) {
        var fileContent = JSON.parse(req.response);
        document.querySelector('.vis').innerHTML = fileContent;
        }
      }
    });
   req.open("POST", "serverUrl");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am doing the changes you suggested but hte div is still empty. I also try to print the filecontent to see if it has the content but it does not even get into the if condition

Comment: That means the file upload post request is not succeeding. Can you check the post call returns status 200 with file content from node server.